# Qt based GUI to execute a shell script

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I have written an application in QT, which is supposed to execute a script, written already on ubuntu 14.04, but its not performing the function as desired. This is the piece of code which I have written.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QProcess process ;
    process.startDetached("/bin/bash", QStringList() << "path to file.sh");
}
```

What I am missing here? Thanx for valuable suggestions.

Comment: Does the .sh file do?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, the .sh file executes and perform all the functionality if i run it manually on terminal.

Comment: I've tried your code and I have not had any problems. file.sh: #!/bin/sh
mkdir test

Comment: Does it make any difference if you allocate the QProcess on the heap (using the new operator) rather than on the stack?  (It might be that the QProcess object's destructor is interfering with the running of the script)

Comment: But its not working for me, don't know why. Everything seems to be correct

Comment: @Jeremy, I have modified  it like this but again the same result.
 
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this) ;
process->start("/bin/bash", QStringList() << "/home/randomuser/file.sh");

Comment: Here's a test for you... if you temporary replace /home/randomuser/file.sh with a file that just contains this line:   echo hi > /tmp/foo.txt     ... and then run your Qt program again, do you see a file /tmp/foo.txt afterwards?   If so, you know the script ran, and it must be something in your particular file.sh that doesn't like executing in a non-interactive terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake, actually the code works well.
When i press the button the GUI creates a new file in the same directory, but i have written the script in home directory. So i was expecting the new file in home directory, but it was already there in project directory.